# "Resource temporarily unavailable" on non-blocking Unix datagram read

Tags: rust, unix-socket

I am writing a process to move data back and forth between instances of itself.

I am receiving the error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', server/src/main.rs:44:37

My current implementation:

````rust
#![feature(duration_constants)]
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::time::Duration;

const OLD_PROCESS: &str = "./old";
const NEW_PROCESS: &str = "./new";

fn startup() {
    // We send the shutdown notification (the data here doesnt matter) then receive the data.
    let socket = UnixDatagram::bind(NEW_PROCESS).unwrap();

    println!("sending shutdown signal");
    socket.send_to(&[1], OLD_PROCESS).unwrap();
    println!("sent shutdown signal");

    println!("reciving data");
    let mut data = [Default::default(); 4];
    socket.recv(&mut data).unwrap();
    println!("data: {:?}", data);

    std::fs::remove_file(NEW_PROCESS).unwrap();
}
fn process() {
    // Once we receive something (indicating a new process has started) we then transfer data.
    let socket = UnixDatagram::bind(OLD_PROCESS).unwrap();

    println!("awaiting shutdown signal");

    // For reading the shutdown signal, we set the socket to non-blocking (like `Mutex::try_read`).
    let mut notif_buf = [0; 1];

    // It seems by setting nonblocking and the read timeout causes the error:
    // ```
    // thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', server/src/main.rs:44:37
    // ```
    socket.set_nonblocking(true).unwrap();
    socket
        .set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::MICROSECOND))
        .unwrap();
    println!("socket.read_timeout(): {:?}", socket.read_timeout());

    // Our work loop
    while notif_buf[0] == 0 {
        // Some other work
        {
            print!(".");
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::MILLISECOND);
        }
        // Check if recieved shutdown signal
        socket.recv(&mut notif_buf).unwrap();
    }
    println!();
    println!("recived shutdown signal");
    socket.set_nonblocking(false).unwrap();

    println!("sending data");
    socket.send_to(&[1, 2, 3, 4], NEW_PROCESS).unwrap();
    println!("sent data");

    std::fs::remove_file(OLD_PROCESS).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // The following processes use it
    if std::path::Path::new(OLD_PROCESS).exists() {
        println!("non-first");
        startup();
        process();
    }
    // The first process creates the socket
    else {
        println!("first");
        process();
    }
}
````

*Notably with this you will need to delete the `old` file descriptor at the end of each test manually for now*

In the simplest sense I want a loop with [UnixDatagram](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/net/struct.UnixDatagram.html#) like (with `try_read` like [`Mutex::try_read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.try_lock)):

```rust
loop {
    // Some work ...
    match socket.try_read() {
        Some(_) => break,
        None => continue
    }
}
```

Comment: That error code (EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN) means there's no datagram available to read on the socket.  So you need to deal with that, rather than unconditionally trying to unwrap the (non-existant) datagram

Comment: If I remove the `set_nonblocking` and `set_read_timeout` calls the programs works as expected. Does this not suggest it can read/write to the socket, there is a datagram available?

Comment: If you remove the non-blocking, the recv call will block until there is a packet.  What do you want to do when there is no packet yet?  You should do that when `recv` returns Err with the EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN code.

Comment: Side note: Calling `unwrap()` all over the place is a pretty bad habit. You should think through what you want to do any time a function returns a `Result`. Handle errors if you can, otherwise propagate them to the caller. `?` makes the latter quite easy; it's even shorter than `.unwrap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using:

```rust
socket.set_nonblocking(true).unwrap();
socket.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::MICROSECOND)).unwrap();
```

it seems when the timeout occurs `recv` returns `Err` thus by changing the code:

```rust
// Check if recieved shutdown signal
socket.recv(&mut notif_buf).unwrap();
```

to

```rust
match socket.recv(&mut notif_buf) {
    Ok(_) => break,
    Err(_) if err.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock => continue,
    _ => unreachable!()
}
```

this fixes the issue.

Comment: `Err(_) =>` is a bad idea, this "swallows" every error, including real errors like permission denied or socket closed. This should match the specific variants for EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: @Shelvacu I updated the check, is this what you mean?